# physical db design block count and frame number

Tags: database, oracle

In the context of physical db design. What is block count, Frame Number, and page id. My book mentions these terms, but it doesn't define them.

Comment: Without any context it's kind of hard to guess what the author might have been referring to. Telling us which book and showing how the terms were used might help, though I don't think this is on-topic for this site anyway. They aren't terms I've ever seem in relation to a database though.

Comment: These are low-level Unix terms. What relevance they have rather depends on what you mean by *"physical db design"* .